# sql query to return all rows with same column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB like

```
    column_1 | column_2 | column_3
    ------------------------------
         aaa | bbb      | ccc
         xys | hkj      | fgh
         dfs | jhv      | ccc
         cfg | rty      | fgh
         iyd | olp      | ccc
         gdv | tdr      | www
```

I want to get the result such that all the rows that have the same value in `column_3` are printed out along with their `column_3` value

```
        column_1 | column_3
        --------------------
             aaa | ccc
             dfs | ccc
             iyd | ccc
             cfg | fgh
             xys | fgh
             gdv | www
```

I know `SELECT DISTINCT column_3 FROM table_name;` gives me all the unique names of `column_3` but how do I get all the `column_1` values that depend on `column_3`?

Comment: If the second box you have is an example of what you would like, then couldn't you just use SELECT DISTINCT column_1, column_3?

Comment: If the second box you have is an example of what you would like, then couldn't you just use `SELECT column_1, column_3 ORDER BY column_3, column_1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ...
From table_name As T
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From table_name As T2
                Where T2.column_3 = T.column_3
                    And T2.<Primary Key Column> <> T.<Primary Key Column>
                )
```

Obviously, you would replace `<Primary Key Column>` with the column(s) that uniquely identify each row in `table_name`. If `column_1` is that column, then we would get:

```
Select ...
From table_name As T
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From table_name As T2
                Where T2.column_3 = T.column_3
                    And T2.column_1 <> T.column_1
                )
```

Comment: And what if only the first portion with same column_3 is needed? Ex. 
    `aaa | ccc`
    `dfs | ccc`
    `iyd | ccc`

Comment: @George - I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking for all rows related to the first column 3 value that is used multiple times? If so, how should the system order the column 3 values? By frequency? By alpha sort?

Comment: Nevermind, I was looking for a way to retrieve all the rows with the column_3 value of 'ccc' but without knowing the value 'ccc'. One possible (and feasible for me) solution is with inner select like this: `select * from table_name where column_3 = (select min(column_3) from table_name)`

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you're overthinking this? I believe you want

```
 SELECT column_1,
        column_3
   FROM table_name
  ORDER BY column_3, column_1
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in MYSQL yet, but in SQL Server this work.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_1 CHAR(3), column_2 CHAR(3), column_3 CHAR(3))
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES 
('aaa','bbb','ccc')
,('xys','hkj','fgh')
,('dfs','jhv','ccc')
,('cfg','rty','fgh')
,('iyd','olp','ccc')
,('gdv','tdr','www')

SELECT column_1  
     , column_3 
  FROM table_name a
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT column_3 
               FROM table_name b
              GROUP BY column_3
             HAVING COUNT(column_3) > 0
                AND b.column_3 = a.column_3)
```